# How to get text between div by Xpath in python

Tags: python, xpath

I have a following line of code:

```
<div class="topText">Text</div>
```

And i want to get "Text" from it as String variable MyText

I have tried to use this:

```
MyText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("string(//div[@class='topText'])")
```

But it gives me an error:
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression string(//div[@class='topText_1SWFA']) because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

I have also tried simple Xpath like:

```
MyText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='topText_1SWFA']/text()")
```

or another alternatives but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '<div class="topText">Text</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
finder = soup.find('div', class_='topText')
text = finder.getText()
```

Comment: What does this code do?

Comment: Thanks for help i have alredy solved that problem